# Error:Execution failed: finished with non-zero exit value 2

Tags: android, gradle

I have a project that worked very good but when added these:

```
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0"
```

This error apearese:

```
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

I update sdk to 1.8.0.25 but this error did not solve. How can i fix it?

My gradle:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.+'
compile 'net.hockeyapp.android:HockeySDK:3.6.+'
compile 'com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.0.+'
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0"

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:+'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.+'
compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.+'
compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
compile 'com.github.dmytrodanylyk.circular-progress-button:library:1.1.3'
compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:1.0.+'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.5.0'
compile 'com.github.rahatarmanahmed:circularprogressview:2.4.0'
compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.1.2'
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

Comment: Put your complete gradle file here please.

Comment: might i ask what's the point of upgrading jdk to 1.8.025 and setting the target compatability to 1.7

Comment: @sahar, Android currently "officially" supports 1.7, don't use 1.8. And you are not using as you can see in the error: 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin\java.exe'. Go to you project path and run "./gradlew build" and see where it fails. Btw, how many libs are you using inside your libs folder. This could be a problem related with multiDex.

Comment: do you think it is for my java SDK version?

Comment: No I don't. How many libs are you importing inside your libs folder?

Comment: I added all compile library in my gradle. in libs folder there are more than those. some library are repetitive in libs folder.

Comment: I think find my problem. Thank you GuilhE.

Comment: Good news. Post your solution as an answer to help others ;)